# Wordpress plugin: Hook on custom url

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a plugin, that I will use for some jQuery AJAX loading of table data.

I have a function that prints the data correctly, but how do I "hook" into a specific url?

Like say, I want the function to be run, and the data to be printed whenever a request to /mycustomplugin/myurl.php is run? (Please note that the url/file should not exist)

I have no experience with WP plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/mycustomplugin/myurl.php') {
  echo "<my ajax code>";
}
```

Should work wonders.

Comment: This only works fine if you don't want to use any Wordpress functionality in your request. It would be executed before init.

Comment: You neglected to specify where one might put this url.

Answer (score 41):

To filter your custom URL before Wordpress starts executing queries for other things use something like this:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'my_custom_url_handler');

function my_custom_url_handler() {
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/custom_url') {
      echo "<h1>TEST</h1>";
      exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this works only in the front-end, I'd probably use a different action hook, not sure which one (`wp` vs `admin_init`).

Comment: Being totally ignorant about WordPress API, I will have to ask: Where should one put this code? I would like to use this method in a plugin and I don't want to edit WP pre-existing files, but only my plugin's files.

Comment: OK. I have put in in my pluging's file (inside `wp-content\plugins`) as it is, I activated the plugin, but it doesn't work... :( I wonder why...

Comment: @NoOne you cant use plugin without initialize codes before use it . Anyway you can put this code on your theme `function.php` file . PS @zarazan you use `parse_request` to make it run before WP start pharsing url path etc , so the url wont get WP 404 error page .

Comment: The idea is good, but this action doesn't work for some reason. I'll look it up for WP 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return regular wordpress data you could just include wp-blogheader.php into your custom php file like so

```
//Include Wordpress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('Your_Word_Press_Directory/wp-blog-header.php');
query_posts('showposts=10&cat=2');
```

Just use regular theming tags to return the content you desire.  This

Where is your table data coming from though?  Are you trying to show this information on the admin side or the viewer side?

Also see  for a full breakdown of calling hooked functions with wp_ajax http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_url_handler' );

function my_url_handler() {
     if( isset( $_GET['unique_hidden_field'] ) ) {
          // process data here
     }
}
```

using `add_action( 'init', 'your_handler')` is the most common way in plugins since [this action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) is fired after WordPress has finished loading, but before any headers are sent. Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated.